# Django: Correct way to save HTML code inside database

Tags: html, django, postgresql, django-views, django-orm

I want to save HTML code inside my Postgresql database so that I can directly send this code as HttpResponse instead of serving static HTML file. I did saved it inside database but following error keeps on coming.
[image: Error after returning html code]

What is correct way of doing this task?

Edit1: code of views.py file

```
def index(request):

    index_object = StaticWebPage.objects.get(page_title='index')

    return HttpResponse(
        request,
        index_object.page_content
    )
```

Comment: Please (if you can) paste the code you are using as your view.

Comment: @McAbra Ok wait posting code

Comment: @McAbra added views.py code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to make a template backend that will keep your templates in the data base and not in the file system? If so: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#custom-backends

I can see that in that `StaticWebPage` record you have a Django template, to render that you'll need to treat is as a string and render that as you would when rendering strings.

```
from django.template import Template, Context

def index(request):
    index_object = StaticWebPage.objects.get(page_title='index')
    template = Template(index_object.page_content)
    return HttpResponse(
        content=template.render(Context({})),  # use the context or not
        content_type=None,
        status=200,
        reason=None,
        charset=None,
    )
```

(In Django 1.10) `django.http.response.HttpResponse` does not take `request` as the first argument (I added the args it takes for reference).

Comment: @aVIRA Please elaborate, only then I'll be able to aid you

Comment: after making GET request to url, output is None.

Comment: So my code is working (it's not broken like throwing an exception) but it did not resolve you problem?  
Does your `StaticWebPage.objects.get(page_title='index').page_content` equal to `None` by any chance?

Comment: no it is not equal to None. Now code i saved is plane HTML code. Can you please share your HTML code as gist so that I could test it.